# Can GUIZERO develop by sensor? If possible, how? (Using If Elif and Else statement?)

Tags: python, guizero

Can GUIZERO be used for developing with sensors, or is GPIOZERO required?
I'm new to python and programming in general.
I want to develope a *Lift and Learn* project. I have no idea how to create the script.

Here is my idea:

- The display shows 5 different pictures
- if pic 1 is *lifted up*, the display shows the description. The other pictures do not be move.
- similarly if picture 2 is *lifted up* other picture do not be move
- if both picture 1 and 2 are *lifted up*, pictures 3 and 5 will not be moving.

Anyone have any idea how to write this kind of coding?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first project, start small! Start building a software-only prototype with only GUIZERO.

First [install the library](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/#installation) then see the [getting started documentation](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/start/).

You will need GPIOZERO (or alternative) later on to communicate with sensors.

Comment: Okay, so i will need to use GPIOZERO to communicate with sensor, thankyou so much